# Laravel get collection orderBy relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table chart

```
-compet_id
-team_id
-score
```

table rencontre

```
-rencontre_id
-team_1_id
-team_2_id
-compet_id
```

Rencontre model relation :

```
public function compet(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Compet' , 'compet_id');

    }
```

here the begin of my query :

```
public function getRencontresByChart(){

       $rencontres = Rencontres::all();

}
```

> I need to get a collection of rencontres orderBy the best teams score.

I'm not sure how to achieve that with this model design

Answer (score 1):

There is several ways to achive. Eg.

```
$rencontres = Rencontres::orderBy('score')->get();
```

or using sortBy:

```
$rencontres = Rencontres::all()->sortBy('score');
$rencontres = Rencontres::all()->sortByDesc('score');
```

EDIT: maybe I don't have the whole picture by looking the original post. If you want to order by an aux model, you can do this:

```
$rencontres = Rencontres::with('compet')->get()->sortBy('compet.score');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply the problem is i need to sortBy score form chart table

Comment: should i put rencontre_id in chart table ?